# how to do colormap to color table-cell background using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I am using pycharm to output this table using matplotlib library. However i want to colour the cells based on the values. [image]

The code i have so far is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
table_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

table_data =table_data.astype({"Runs":int, "HS":int})
table_data =table_data.sort_values(by='HS')
df = table_data


table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
        colLabels=df.columns,
        loc="center",
        cellLoc="left")
table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(df.columns))))
plt.show()
```

the output should look like the column "BasePay" and "OtherPay" (refer to the image below) for the "HS" column and "S/R" column of my dataset. [image]

I tried using styling libraries on python, but they do not print locally on pycharm therefore i need it as a plt.show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the background color of a cell, you can either use the corresponding list of colors you want to decorate, or you can use a color map to create a list of colors by data value to decorate. For the latter method, I tried seaborn's palette and matplotlib's method. seaborn's palette was applied to the HS column since the data is in ascending order. in a new column and reorder it in the original order. Then decorate the target column with the reordered list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
table_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

table_data =table_data.astype({"Runs":int, "HS":int})
table_data =table_data.sort_values(by='HS')
df = table_data

table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
        colLabels=df.columns,
        loc="center",
        cellLoc="left")
table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(df.columns))))

# sns color palette use(data:ascending)
bcmap = sns.mpl_palette("Blues", len(table_data['HS'].unique()))
for idx,b in enumerate(bcmap):
    table[(idx+1, 6)].set_facecolor(b)

# matplotlib colormap
from matplotlib import cm
vals = table_data['S/R']
normal = cm.colors.Normalize(vals.min(), vals.max())
bcmap2 = plt.cm.Blues(normal(vals))

for idx, bb in enumerate(bcmap2):
    table[(idx+1, 10)].set_facecolor(bb)

plt.show()
```

[image]